# Search bar widths across the sites

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

Why does the search bar in Super User and Server Fault have a width much larger than the search bar on other Stack Exchange sites like The Workplace?

Why are these not consistent?

Comment: @rene - But it seems silly to constantly post these bugs - there is no review of this.  How am I the one that finds most of these?  Its the first  thing that I noticed when opening any of the sites.

Comment: @JonH well, it is probably the same problem I have with the software I deliver: I always have the UX peeps point out the glitches to me while I promised myself last time to not get caught by those same silly mistakes. I call it UX design blindness and most devs suffer from it. No cure yet :(

Comment: @JonH We are looking into this.

Comment: For some reason some sites are missing the CSS rule `max-width: 400px;` hence the search box is too wide. (Leaving this to the team to fix.)

Comment: @Adam yet again a missing rule... maybe some CSS change has been reverted by mistake to something before rolling out the new top bar across the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. I have pushed a fix internally, and now waiting for the next build for the fix to be published across those sites.

Should be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in couple hours.